# Error when building Gatsby website: window is not defined

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm having issues to "gatsby build" this website, this is the only place I've used window I think and keeps getting me this error. Is there any workaround to fix this? In gatsy develop everything is fine.
My code is:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { tooltipData, burgerData } from "../../data/menuData";
import MenuButton from "../buttons/MenuButton";

export default function MenuTooltip(props) {
  const { isOpen } = props;

  if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
    return (
      <Wrapper isOpen={isOpen}>
        {burgerData.map((item, index) => (
          <MenuButton item={item} key={index} />
        ))}
      </Wrapper>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <Wrapper isOpen={isOpen}>
        {tooltipData.map((item, index) => (
          <MenuButton item={item} key={index} />
        ))}
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There's a page dedicated to this in the Gatsby documentation: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course there's a workaround. Just wrap your condition in:

```
  if(typeof window !== 'undefined'){
    if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
      return (
        <Wrapper isOpen={isOpen}>
          {burgerData.map((item, index) => (
            <MenuButton item={item} key={index} />
          ))}
        </Wrapper>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <Wrapper isOpen={isOpen}>
          {tooltipData.map((item, index) => (
            <MenuButton item={item} key={index} />
          ))}
        </Wrapper>
      );
    }
  else return null
  }
```

As you can see in the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/), the suggested workaround is to wrap the window usage in `typeof window !== 'undefined'` condition. Essentially, this is because `gatsby build` occurs in the server, where there's no `window` (or other global objects such as `document`, because they're not being created yet) while in `gatsby develop` there's.